# How can I get the contents of a file above webroot (located at home dir)

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I want to store the password of my database to a file not into the webroot as directed by many repliers to relevant answers here.

I want to read the file from the dir "~/".
How to do that?

I've tried `$file_content = file_get_contents("~/pass", true);` but when I `echo $file_content` it prints nothing.

Comment: What does `var_dump($file_content);` output? `echo` is not the best to check variable values and types. Then compare with the documentation of the return value of that function: http://php.net/file_get_contents - e.g. if it is `FALSE`, you find an explanation there. And do not forget to enable error display and logging to the highest level, trace the messages (e.g. by following the log) and tell us which warnings and notices you see and how you explain them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading to an FTP server, use something like FileZilla and you should see your document root.

For me, it's /home/myusername/public_html.
If you had a file in myfolder above the web root, assume it will be /home/myusername/myfolder/file.

Then do `file_get_contents(thingimentionedabove);`.

Although I would recommend putting your document within the web root and granting / disallowing access via permissions in a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

The classical way to do that would be a config.php in a web app subdirectory, setting database access variables like $password. As security is concerned, "config" is too obvious.

Also all php scripts that deliver files should be programmed restrictively.